# Error when trying to add an Azure Blob Storage URI to an Azure Storage Table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I'm trying to add images to Azure blob storage, (this part of the program works correctly).

Once each image is in the blob storage I want to create an Azure storage table with an entity having two columns. The image category, and the image URI.

When I try to insert into the Azure Storage Table the application enters "break mode".

Ultimately this will be used by a mobile app that uses the table to select image URIs as the imagesource for a grid view so I need the full URI.

I've hardcoded the category to try and narrow down the problem.

I'm using the Azure Storage Emulator during development. FYI.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureEmulatorTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string localPath = "./data/";
            const string containerName = "mycontainer";
            const string tableName = "mytable";

            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(@"UseDevelopmentStorage=true");

            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
            await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(localPath);

            foreach (var images in filenames)
            {
                string _imageBlobReference = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";

                var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(_imageBlobReference);
                await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(images);
                string blobUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

                ImageFile image = new ImageFile("Birthday", blobUrl);

                await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(image));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Files Uploaded... Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class ImageFile : TableEntity
    {
        public ImageFile(string Category, string ImageURL)
        {
            PartitionKey = Category;
            RowKey = ImageURL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to not put the URL in the PartitionKey or Rowkey properties.

When I added a string property to the table, I was able to add the URL without issue.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the issue is with the value of your `RowKey` attribute as it contains invalid character (`/`).

For a list of unallowed characters in `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`, please see this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model.

To solve this problem, please URL encode the entire URL and then try to save it. That should work.